# C# - How to bind header text on gridview from dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to bind header text on gridview from dataset table.

**Dataset Table1:**

```
S.No     Employee        15-Feb    16-Feb    17-Feb

 1       Kumar             1          2        3

 2       Jeeva             1          2        3
```

I want to bind these date(15-Feb,16-Feb,17-Feb) on gridview header, these are coming dynamically from Database

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have to add columns dynamically from code behind. Your Date column does not make sense if you might have multiple dates from the DB.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="15-Feb">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblProjectName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="16-Feb">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblActivityDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ActivityDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```